# Is there a way to change the saturation on the main camera in unity using a C# script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I am trying to create an effect where the camera goes to black and white for a short period of time and then returns to normal in unity 2019. Does anyone know how to achieve this using a C# script?

Answer (score 1):

I would set up [Post Processing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessingOverview.html) in your project. After that, you can directly set the [Color Grading](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@3.1/manual/Color-Grading.html), which contains the field `Saturation`. [image: How to create a new post-processing profile]

The attached image shows how to create a `Post-Processing Profile`. After creating the object, follow along the [Quick Start](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@3.0/manual/Quick-start.html) in Unity's docs.

After setting up your post-processing, I would follow [this Unity Forum's Post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1355103/modifying-the-new-post-processing-stack-through-co.html) on how to edit the values at runtime. To fade in and out the values, use a [Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html).

If all of this is too complicated, you can also create a simple fade using a [screen space canvas](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html), and an Image object that you fade the color of using [Color Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html). You can make it fade from `Color.Clear` to `Color.White` and/or `Color.Black`

The other option would be a [shader](https://www.programmersought.com/article/364774976/), but this solution is much more involved than the other two.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a material to your camera by using the `OnRenderImage` method and then modify the material values as needed. This would allow you to add any kind of effect that you need as long as you have the necessary shader.

### Solution

Attach the following script to a `Camera`, reference a `Material` and modify the values as needed:

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class CameraEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material material;

    private void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
    {
        if (material == null)
        {
            Graphics.Blit(source, destination);
            return;
        }

        Graphics.Blit(source, destination, material);
    }
}
```

### Example

Here's an example script and a shader which allows you to fade the `Camera` view to a black color and back. The script expects a `Material` which uses the shader provided down below.

[Video preview](https://streamable.com/h4oj7q)

#### Script (.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class FadeTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private CameraEffect effect = null;

    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 1f;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(FadeOutAndIn(() => 
            Debug.Log("Screen is dark now, fading back in")));
    }

    public IEnumerator FadeOutAndIn(Action midpointAction)
    {
        yield return FadeTowards(0f);
        midpointAction?.Invoke();
        yield return FadeTowards(1f);
    }

    private IEnumerator FadeTowards(float target)
    {
        float value = effect.material.GetFloat("_Value");

        while (value != target)
        {
            value = Mathf.MoveTowards(value, target, Time.deltaTime * speed);
            effect.material.SetFloat("_Value", value);

            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Shader (.shader)

```
Shader "Custom/Dark"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Value ("Value", Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 0.0
    }
    SubShader
    {
        // No culling or depth
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _Value;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                col.rgb = col.rgb * _Value;
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```